# LCD NOKIA 5110 how to change only part of text/lines

Tags: lcd

I don't known if it's specially a raspberry oriented question, but it is related to my raspberry project then ...

My question is in the title, how to refresh a certain part of the NOKIA 5110 screen ? For example, how to display and refresh the datetime every 1 second without deleting all other text/lines ? It's is possible, or it is not possible because it is how the screen work (need erasing all block before writing same as EEPROM default writing for example) ?

I use [Adafruit_Nokia_LCD library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Nokia_LCD).
I have also look in the example file '[animate.py](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Nokia_LCD/blob/master/examples/animate.py)', but for every 'frame' all screen is 'clear' before display...

```
def clear(self):
    """Clear contents of image buffer."""
    self._buffer = [0] * (LCDWIDTH * LCDHEIGHT // 8)
```

I don't want this. I want this [example counter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZvY_lb6BoU).

Thank for your help.

Comment: it looks like the whole screen gets reloaded each time ... i see no reason why the screen has to be cleared ... run a test where you set a few dots on the screen and then clear some of them, but do not clear the whole screen

Comment: @jsotola After asking my question, I ended up thinking like you. I have not tried yet but I will do it in the coming hours. Thank you for your opinion and recommendations.